# Capacitive Moisture sensor only shows values 1 and 2

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I'm new to Arduino and electronics in general. I'm trying to connect the Capacitive moisture sensor v1.2 to my arduino and get values in the serial plotter.
I connected the VCC to 5V, GRD to ground and AOUT to A0. However, I keep only getting values of 1, 2 or 3, while they are supposed to be in the hundreds. What could be a cause of such a problem. I'm using the chinese Wavgat board, but I have previously connected the moisture and humidity sensors and they displayed values normally.

Here's the code I used:

```
int val;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  val = analogRead(A0);
  Serial.println(val);
  delay(200);
}
```

Comment: What's a capacitive moisture sensor v1.2?

Comment: Assuming [this](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4026) is what you have, did you go through the [OverView for this product](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-stemma-soil-sensor-i2c-capacitive-moisture-sensor) including installing the Adafruit_seesaw library?

Comment: Ah, not the expensive digital board.  This board has an analog output. At this point you need to start testing and swapping out parts.  Test the voltage at AOUT to verify it does in fact change when dipping the sensor in water.  Try a different sensor.  They are cheep and maybe you have a defective one.  Try a different Arduino.   Maybe the ADC input is broken on the one you have.